# how to exclude empty field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using the Track and Album tables, write a query that returns all the songs that start with the letter 'A' and the composer field is not empty. Your query should return the name of the song, the name of the composer, and the title of the album.

I used this query but no result

```
SELECT t.name name , a.Title Title, t.Composer
FROM Track t
JOIN Album a
on a.AlbumId = t.AlbumId
where t.name like 'a%' and t.Composer not in ''  ;
```

Comment: Your `JOIN` is missing an `ON` clause.  That is probably the root of your problem.

Comment: `t.Composer not in ''` is not valid SQL. [`in`](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_in.asp) is for multiple values, it must be a list like `not in (1,2,3)`. To check if a single value is not equal use `t.Composer <> ''`.

Comment: Did they explain if "empty" means empty string or null?

Comment: i did but no result unless i delete (and t.Composer not in '') but it is not the needed result of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.name name , a.Title Title, t.Composer
FROM Track t
JOIN Album a on a.Id = t.AlbumId
where t.name like 'a%' and t.Composer is NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to be something like this:

```
SELECT t.name name , a.Title Title, t.Composer
FROM 
  Track t
  JOIN Album a ON t.AlbumId = a.Id
where t.name like 'a%' and composer <> '';
```

You'll need to fix the names in the ON clause to reflect how your tables relate. If you wanted to use IN, it'd look more like: `IN('a', 'b')` - it needs parentheses around the lis tof values (which could be one value, but if you only had one value you'd just use `=`)

Comment: `coalesce(t.composer, '') <> ''` would cover both null and empty string.

Comment: I know; but there isn't any need to check for null if you're testing for `x <> something` as it's false if x is null (strictly speaking, it's null if x is null, which will eventually be interpreted as false). I'm aiming to pitch the answer to the level of the question; it seems likely to be homework, and COALESCE probably hasn't been taught

Comment: You say this solved the problem, and then you accept the other answer, which is probably incorrect.. bizarre